# JSON Syntax error when getting data to my Ionic app

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I'm trying to get data from JSON url from a Wordpress website to my ionic app , it shows me this error :

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ? in JSON at position 4885
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at fromJson (ionic.bundle.js:14660)
at defaultHttpResponseTransform (ionic.bundle.js:23680)
at ionic.bundle.js:23771
at forEach (ionic.bundle.js:13696)
at transformData (ionic.bundle.js:23770)
at transformResponse (ionic.bundle.js:24559)
at processQueue (ionic.bundle.js:29132)
at ionic.bundle.js:29148
at Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:30400)
```

this is my json url
http://www.casting.tunisiebillet.com/api/get_posts/?count=93

and this is how my angularjs controller works :
`$scope.recent_posts=[];
    $http.get("http://www.casting.tunisiebillet.com/api/get_posts/?count=93").then(function(data){
        console.log(data);`

I think there is an error with the JSON syntax , how can I fix it please ?
Thank you .

Comment: Can You show a line of code at position 4885?

Comment: Are you using `JSON.parse()` at line `4885` ?

Comment: I'm just using $http.get in my controller , and please @Rafalsonn how can I get the position 4885 in my file ?

Comment: I think it's a 4885 sign from the beginning, but I'm not sure, it depends how this parser is working.

Comment: I tried with a json validator it says 
Error: Parse error on line 77:
...: [
"a:1:{i:0;s:1:"0";}"
],
"sbg_sele
----------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ':', ',', ']', got 'NUMBER'